# Berry Esseen inequality for multidimensional distributions

Tags: pr.probability, fourier-analysis

The classical Berry-Esseen theorem asserts that if $f$ and $g$ are the characteristic functions of two distribution functions $F(t)$ and $G(t)$ respectively then with $T$ arbitrary
$$
\sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} |F(t) - G(t)| \ll \frac{1}{T} + \int_{-T}^{T} \bigg | \frac{f(t) - g(t)}{t} \bigg | dt
$$
provided that one of the $F$ or $G$ is in Schwartz class (say). Is there a generalization of this inequality for distribution functions in $\mathbb{R}^k$, with $k = 2$ specifically? Precisely, I'm looking for a bound for
$$
\sup_{\mathcal{R}} |\mathbb{P}(X \in \mathcal{R}) - \mathbb{P}(Y \in \mathcal{R}) |
$$
in terms of the characteristic functions of $X$ and $Y$, with $X,Y$ random variables
in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\mathcal{R}$ rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: There are many ways to bound that quantity. Why does it have to be in term of characteristic functions in particular?

Answer (score 2):

The sharpest multidimensional Berry--Esseen Theorem I know is due to Bentkus and appears in the paper "A Lyapunov type bound in ${\mathbb R}^d$".

http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0040585X97981123

It does not use the characteristic function, though.

Comment: There's now also the follow-up work in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.06475 which has explicit constants.

Answer (score 1):

There are many results along those lines in Bhattacharya and Rao, *Normal Approximation and Asymptotic Expansions*.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a higher dimensional analogue of the so-called Berry-Esseen inequality and ran into this unanswered question.

For a two dimensional analogue look at Theorem 1 and its Corollary in the paper
*On two-dimensional analogues of an inequality of Esseen and their application to the central limit theorem* by  S.M. Sadikova. It is mentioned here that the proof of the result generalizes to higher dimensions.

For an explicit statement of the general higher dimensional analogue look at Theorem 2 and Corollary 2.2 of the paper *Higher dimensional quasi-power theorem
and Berry–Esseen inequality* by Clemens Heuberger and Sara Kropf.